# Why was a seemingly constructive comment on an answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

I complimented an answer to [How to summon an Invisible Stalker?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68025/how-to-summon-an-invisible-stalker) in a comment today, and also requested whether the answer could be expanded to include magical items (possibly from *Princes of the Appocalypse* adventuring supplement, which has elemental themes), and not only spells as Miniman had done a beautiful job of detailing.

My comment was deleted, and I am befuddled as to why asking for an elaboration on a well-answered question is seen as deletion-worthy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no deleted comments on that question or its answers.  In your main site activity I see only one comment posted today.  Perhaps you thought you hit save and didn't? But this appears to be what we like to call a "wetware error."

Comment: Huh! I will be darned... will resubmit. :)